# SQL query_select different column based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

These are my two tables:

- Table1 has start date and end date.
- Table2 has AllMonths and Month and Value column.

Scripts to create these tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [EmployeeId] [int] NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] VALUES(12345,1205,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2021-06-30 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] VALUES(23211,1205,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2021-05-31 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] VALUES(23211,1205,'2021-07-01 00:00:00.000','2021-09-30 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] VALUES(23141,1205,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2021-11-30 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] values(54333,1205,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2021-05-31 00:00:00.000') 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] values(76553,1205,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2021-12-31 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] values(55555,1205,'2021-08-01 00:00:00.000','2021-09-30 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] values(55555,1205,'2021-11-01 00:00:00.000','2021-11-30 00:00:00.000')


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [EmployeeId] [int] NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NULL,
    [AllMonths] [int] NULL,
    [Month] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,1,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,2,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,3,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,4,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,5,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,6,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,7,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,8,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,9,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,11,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23211,1205,NULL,12,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(23141,1205,1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,1,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,2,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,3,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,4,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,5,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,6,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,7,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,8,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,9,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,11,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(12345,1205,NULL,12,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,1,1) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,2,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,3,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,4,2) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,5,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,6,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,7,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,8,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,9,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,10,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,11,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,12,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,1,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,2,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,3,2) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,4,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,5,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,6,2) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,7,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,8,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,9,2) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,10,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,11,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,12,NULL)
```

My desired output is:

[image]

- Case #1: EmployeeId = 12345

  `AllMonths` column is NULL. `Startdate` Jan and `EndDate` Jun. All these months from jan-jun have the same value in table 2. So the 'EmployeeClass' value is 1.
- Case #2: EmployeeId = 23211

  `AllMonths` column is NULL. `Startdate` Jan and `EndDate` May and `Startdate` July and `EndDate` Sep. Jan-Mar have a value of 1 while Apr-May have a value of 2 in table 2. So in the output it should be split into two rows, Jan-Mar the 'EmployeeClass' value is 1 and Apr-May value is 2.Also for July-Sep, have a value of 2 so there is one more row for July-Sep with value 2.
- Case #3: EmployeeId = 23141

  `AllMonths` column is NOT NULL. So 'Final' value is 1 from `AllMonths` column.
- Case #4: EmployeeId = 54333

  `AllMonths` column is NULL. `Startdate` Jan and `EndDate` May. jan have a value of 1 and feb-may have a value of 2 in table 2. So in the output it should be split into two rows, Jan-Jan the 'EmployeeClass' value is 1 and Feb-May value is 2.
- Case #5: EmployeeId = 55555

  two rows for this employee in table1. But no rows in table 2. So these rows shld be availble in the output with 'EmployeeClass' value 'NULL'.
- Case #6: EmployeeId = 76553

  `AllMonths` column is NULL. `Startdate` Jan and `EndDate` Dec. jan have a value of 1 and feb-oct have a value of 2  and nov-dec have a value of 3 in table 2. So in the output it should be split into three rows, Jan-Jan the 'EmployeeClass' value is 1 and Feb-Oct value is 2 and Nov-Dec value is 'NULL'.

Need some help on achieving this.

Comment: Please create tables with sample data in it, its tasking recreating them from excel screenshots. You can use tools like [Markdown Table Generator](https://tableconvert.com/markdown-generator) to quickly paste your data in and create a markdown table to paste here when you edit your question.

Comment: I edited the question with scripts for table added

Comment: SQL server version? Also, do you have a numbers table or a calendar table?

Comment: Azure SQL Server...So looking for solution without any system number tables.

Comment: Change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN in the script that I provided (which also seems to be working for your new sample data)  to get employees that do not exist in Table2 in the results.

Comment: @PRI,did you check my script.The output matches exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 logic ,

i) when allmonths is null
ii) allmonths is not null

First create Number table in whatever way you want,

```
Create Table tblNumber(Number int primary key)

INSERT INTO tblNumber
SELECT TOP 100000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [N]
FROM dbo.syscolumns tb1,dbo.syscolumns tb2
```

Final Script,

```
   select *
,ROW_NUMBER()over( partition by employeeid order by companyid)rn1
into #table1
from table1

;with CTE as
(
select T1.*
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by rn1,employeeid order by companyid)rn
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by employeeid order by companyid)rn2
,DATEDIFF(month,startdate,enddate)+1monthDiff from #table1 T1
inner join [dbo].[tblNumber1] n on n.number<=(DATEDIFF(month,startdate,enddate)+1)
)
,CTE2 as
(
select T1.*
,dateadd(month,(rn-1),t1.startdate)NewEndDate
from CTE T1

)
,CTE1 as
(
select t1.companyid,t1.employeeid,t1.startdate,dateadd(month,(rn-1),t1.startdate)NewEndDate
,t1.Enddate,rn,rn1
,t2.[value] as Final 
from CTE2 t1
cross apply(select top 1 [value] from table2 t2 where t2.employeeid=t1.employeeid 
and t2.companyid=t1.companyid and month=month(NewEndDate) and allmonths is null)t2
union all
select t1.companyid,t1.employeeid,t1.startdate,dateadd(month,(rn-1),t1.startdate)NewEndDate
,t1.Enddate,rn,rn1
,t2.[allmonths] as Final 
from CTE2 t1
cross apply(select top 1 allmonths from table2 t2 where t2.employeeid=t1.employeeid 
and t2.companyid=t1.companyid  and allmonths is not null)t2

)


select * from
(
select companyid, employeeid,min(NewEndDate)StartDate,eomonth(max(NewEndDate)) EndDate,Final
from CTE1
group by companyid, employeeid,Final,rn1
union all

select t1.companyid,t1.employeeid,t1.startdate,EndDate
,null as Final 
from #table1 t1
where not exists(select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.employeeid=t1.employeeid 
and t2.companyid=t1.companyid  )

)t4
order by employeeid,StartDate

drop table #table1
```

Point to note

i) I took  sample data some hour ago.

ii) Test with other sample data and if it do not work with other sample data then paste that sample data seperately.

iii) How many rows are involve in all both table ?

iv) First let the output get corrected then query can be optimized.

v) First test when "allmonths is null" with various sample data

vi) Then  test when "allmonths is not null" with various sample data

Comment: INSERT INTO Table1 values(54333,1205,2021,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2021-05-31 00:00:00.000') INSERT INTO Table1 values(76553,1205,2021,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2021-12-31 00:00:00.000')

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,1,1) INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,2,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,3,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,4,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,5,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,6,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,7,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,8,1)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,9,1)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,11,1)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(54333,1205,NULL,12,1)

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,1,1)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,2,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,3,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,4,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,5,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,6,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,7,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,8,2)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,9,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,10,2)

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,11,NULL)INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] VALUES(76553,1205,NULL,12,NULL)

Comment: It fails for the above input with EmployeeId-54333.

Comment: EmployeeId-76553, Need to handle NULL in 'Value' field too...forgot to mention in the question. Also If there is a entry in table1. But no entry for that employee in table2, then too we that employee with start date and end date and 'NULL' for Final column shld be in the result

Comment: @PRI,i) you hv not shown desire output for EmployeeId-54333.output seem ok to me ii)`EmployeeId-76553, Need to handle NULL in 'Value'` again you hv not shown desire output.i am waiting

Comment: Have added the desired output as pic in the question....

Comment: Employee-55555...has two entries in table1. but no rows in table2....so script is INSERT INTO[dbo].[Table1] values(55555,1205,2021,'2021-08-01 00:00:00.000','2021-09-30 00:00:00.000')INSERT INTO[dbo].[Table1] values(55555,1205,2021,'2021-11-01 00:00:00.000','2021-11-30 00:00:00.000')

Comment: @PRI, i) I request you to paste the sample data from here to main question and revise it. ii) I request you revise the desire output in both the case.I am sure it is conflicting. iii)As per you second output enddate should always be last day of month,then it should apply to first output also iv) Output of 54333 should also apply to other employee like 12345.First let us freeze the requirment

Comment: @PRI  v) Also you missing year column in both the table without it how i know if date will like 2021-01-01 or 2022-01-01

Comment: have edited the the question with full details...please have a look at it...Sorry that there is no year column and have removed it...These dates may be across years too...startdate in 2019 and enddate in 2020....

Comment: @KumarHarsh....hope now the requirement is clear....waiting for your input...TIA

Comment: @PRI,sorry for late reply.Check my latest script,it matches exactly with your input.Also delete some of your comment from here where you have posted sample data

Answer (score 0):

This returns your desired output from the sample data you supplied:

```
SELECT 
    t1.CompanyId
    ,t1.EmployeeId
    ,StartDate  = FORMAT(ISNULL(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(StartDate), min(t2.month), 1), StartDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
    ,EndDate    = FORMAT(
                    ISNULL(
                        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(enddate), max(t2.month), 1)
                        ,DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dd, enddate) + 1, enddate)
                    )
                    , 'MM/dd/yyyy')
    ,ISNULL(Allmonths, value) as Final
FROM [Table1] t1
INNER JOIN [Table2] t2 on t1.employeeid = t2.employeeid
                    AND t1.CompanyId = t2.CompanyId
                    AND (   (t2.allmonths IS NOT NULL) 
                            OR (t2.month BETWEEN DATEPART(MM, startdate) AND DATEPART(MM, enddate))
                        )
GROUP BY 
    t1.CompanyId
    ,t1.EmployeeId
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
    ,ISNULL(Allmonths, value)
ORDER BY 
    1, 3, 4
```

Comment: Yes....for most case it works perfect...If i edit the entry for employee-54333, so that end date is 2021-12-31, it fails........INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] values(54333,1205,'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2021-12-31 00:00:00.000') . Expected output  is  jan-jan value is1, feb-jul is 2 and aug-dec is 1.....(three rows)....but i get two rows jan-dec is 1 and feb-jul is 2....Can you help me on this plese